# React Router and framer motion Animate Presence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

When I added 'exitBeforeEnter' prop to the Animate Presence component with nested routes, the routes didn't render at all but when I refreshed the page they rendered, removing this prop or go to the component directly will fix it, but I need to use the prop and the redirect component from react-router

This is my code:

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
                <Switch location={this.props.location} key={this.props.location.pathname} >
                    <Route exact path='/home' component={() => <.../>

                    <Route path='/home/:alpha3Code' component={({match}) =>
                        .... />

                    <Redirect to='/home' />
                </Switch>
</AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 2):

from [exitBeforeEnter](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#animatepresenceprops.exitbeforeenter) docs

> If set to `true`, `AnimatePresence` will only render one component at a time. The exiting component will finished its exit animation before the entering component is rendered.

You have to specify `exit` animations for all components that you are using inside `AnimatePresence`. On route changes, `AnimatePresence` will execute `exit` animations first and then only it will render next component. If a component does not have `exit` animation and it is child of `AnimatePresence`, then route change will only change the url not the view.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal if you will not add an `exit` animation to each and every routes.

Main route with AnimatePresense

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  <Switch location={window.location} key={window.location.pathname}>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
    <Route path="*">Page not found</Route>
  </Switch>
</AnimatePresence
```

About.jsx

```
const exit = {
  exit: {
   opacity: 0,
  },
}
export default function About() {
  return <motion.h1 {...exit}>Hello</h1>
}
```

Home.jsx

```
const exit = {
  exit: {
   opacity: 0,
  },
}
export default function Home() {
  return <motion.h1 {...exit}>Hello</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you still lost, you need to wrap the <motion.div> tag AROUND the < redirect > tag with an "exit" parameter as mentioned in the other answers. Example code is provided below.

```
return (
            <motion.div exit='exit' variants={PageTransition} initial='hidden' animate='show' className='login-container'>
                <Redirect to='/Dashboard' />
            </motion.div>
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

Does anyone have an update with react-router-dom v6 ?

I'm rewriting a small app I made some months ago, and it was working perfectly before, with `AnimatePresence` and `Switch` Router components. Exit transitions were running successfully between pages changes.

Now for some reason, exit transitions don't trigger on page change, and I suspect it may be because of the changes made to react-router-dom API and components use.

In react-router-dom v6, it looks more like that :

```js
const App = function () {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route
              path="characters"
              element={<Characters />}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};
```

And the `Layout` component :

```js
<motion.div
  key="layout"
  initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
  animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
  exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
  transition={{ duration: 0.7 }}
>
  <Menu />
  <div>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
</motion.div>
```

Exit transition doesn't trigger, unfortunately.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70239392/9845867). It has a working example with React Router v6.