# React-router-dom (v6) with Framer Motion (v4)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I am trying to update my react-router-dom to v6, but it seems to be causing issues with framer motions AnimatePresence, specifically the exit transition.

In App.js:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {AnimatePresence} from "framer-motion";  

import Home from "./Components/Home";
import About from "./Components/About";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      {/* globals such as header will go here  */}

      <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And then in my About/Home components I have:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {motion} from "framer-motion";  

    function About() {
    
        const pageMotion = {
            initial: {opacity: 0, x: 0},
            animate: {opacity: 1, x: 50, transition: {duration: 2}},
            exit: {opacity: 0, x:0, transition: {duration: 2}}
        };
    
        return (
            <div className="about">
                <motion.div initial="initial" animate="animate" exit="exit" variants={pageMotion}>about page</motion.div>
                <Link to="/">Go to home page</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default About
```

The "initial" and "animate" work fine, but exit is ignored, and immedietly jumps to the relevant page (rather than animating out first).

Note: I also have had to downgrade to framer-motion v4, as v5 does not work with Create-react-app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to provide to `Routes` the `key` and `location` prop like this:

AnimatedRoutes.js

```js
const AnimatedRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};
```

And since the component that is calling useLocation must be be wrapped in BrowserRouter:

App.js

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AnimatedRoutes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-vc8mr?file=/src/About.js).

Comment: Why is the `location` prop needed? Shouldn't key be sufficient?

Comment: This is working with this config. If you add a Route with a param it wont work. Eg: `<Route path="/hazards/:id" element={<HazardDetails />} />`. If you nav to it and pass it a `state`, the state will be null when unmounting and throw an Error.